# Composer package by branch

Tags: github, branch, composer-php

I have a forked symfony repository in GitHub and I pushed some code to the **2.4** branch.
How can I make Composer use this specific branch?

composer.json:

```
"require" : {
    ...
    "symfony/symfony" : "dev-2.4"
},
"repositories" : {
    "type" : "vcs",
    "url" : "https://github.com/tamirvs/symfony"
}
```

But I get `The requested package symfony/symfony dev-2.4 could not be found`. 
I've also tried `2.4-dev` and `2.4` but I get the same error..

All the info I found on the web got me to what I've already tried.. any ideas?

Please note, that when setting the version to 2.4.* the repository is pulled but without my commits..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you'll need to use `2.4.x-dev`, as outlined [in the documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#branches).

> For example a branch 2.0 will get a version 2.0.x-dev (the .x is added for technical reasons, to make sure it is recognized as a branch, a 2.0.x branch would also be valid and be turned into 2.0.x-dev as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try 2.5-dev.

I believe that the branch has got that version number.

**EDIT:**

Take a look at https://github.com/tamirvs/symfony/blob/master/composer.json

```
"extra": {
  "branch-alias": {
    "dev-master": "2.5-dev"
  }
}
```